# Brew Git Bash Completion with zsh

Tags: git, zsh

I changed from Mac Port to Homebrew

I am using zsh, I installed brew git git-extra and bash-completion. i still don't see git auto completion like mac ports used to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the configs to you .zshrc as below

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash


fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions $fpath)
```

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you need to get [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions)

Comment: Nope, zsh-completions (as the page says) is all about *extra* completions. git zsh completion is built in to zsh (and git comes with a better bash completion as well, but you can use the bash completion in zsh with some work)

Answer (score 3):

## Configuring Completions in zsh

To make Homebrew’s completions available in `zsh`, you must get the Homebrew-managed zsh site-functions on your `FPATH` before initialising `zsh`’s completion facility. Add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
if type brew &>/dev/null
then
  FPATH="$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh/site-functions:${FPATH}"

  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
fi
```

Additionally, if you receive “zsh compinit: insecure directories” warnings when attempting to load these completions, you may need to run this:

```
chmod -R go-w "$(brew --prefix)/share"
```

Source: https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh